# Error when hosting shiny app on DigitalOcean ubuntu server

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, digital-ocean, shiny-server

I have built a shiny app that I have successfully deployed to shinyapps.io in the past. However, since I need better hosting resources and a custom domain, and the only shinyapps.io option allowing for the latter is out of my price range, I am trying to host the app on a digital ocean ubuntu droplet.

I have been able to set up shiny server on my droplet using [this tutorial](https://www.marinedatascience.co/blog/2019/04/28/run-shiny-server-on-your-own-digitalocean-droplet-part-1/). The sample apps work just fine. However, when I try to access my own app (having uploaded it into a directory within my shiny server) I get the following error:

> An error has occurred! An error has occurred. Check your logs or
> contact the app author for clarification.

I've googled for a solution and have tried moving the data cleaning steps from outside the server/ui function into the functions. I have also checked that RStudio on the droplet has all the required packages installed and that seems to be the case. I have checked the logs but there is nothing about this app or the error in the shiny server log. My app works fine both on my local computer and on shinyapps.io. I'd really appreciate any pointers (and apologies if I am duplicating but I haven't found anything that seems directly applicable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - it turns out one of the packages was indeed missing. I had installed them all using my non-root user with admin privileges, and was under the impression they were available globally. One of the packages was not available to root and installing it there resolved the problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue as well on Digital Ocean droplet. For me it's happening if I load the library `plotly`. I tried to reinstall that library using my non-root user but it's still not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @Giacomo, what worked for me was re-installing the library using the root user. Doing it with the non-root user had not worked.

Comment: thanks, I run this command `sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('plotly', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""` in the terminal and it worked. You should accept your answer.
`